# What happens when amber is rubbed with silk?

Tags: electrostatics

We know that amber rubbed with fur/wool will attract small pieces of straw and other light objects. What happens in the case of amber rubbed with silk?

Answer (score 1):

You should know how and why insulators can be electrically charged.When you rub two different insulating materials against each other they do become electrically charged due to exchange of electrons in between them.

Comment: The question is who will release electron amber rod or silk.

Comment: Your question is no longer related to physics but has more to do with organic chemistry still I'll answer it.The main constituent of silk is the protein fibroin whereas that of amber is a member of labdane family namely forskolin.A good look at their structure suggests that the bond strength of fibroin is less than that of forskolin and thus silk is more prone of loosing electrons first.Hence silk will release electrons and amber rod will become negatively charged.

Answer (score 0):

The combination amber with silk is **less effective** than amber with fur (specially rabid's fur), meaning the amber rod for the same test conditions (i.e. time and strength of rubbing) will be less negatively charged when rubbed with silk than if it was  rubbed with fur.

This is because silk is less positive than fur in the [Triboelectric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Triboelectric_series) table.

["A material towards the bottom of the series, when touched to a material near the top of the series, will acquire a more negative charge."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Triboelectric_series)

So expect in general amber electrostatically charged rods to be less effective when rubbed with silk than when rubbed with fur, especially rabbit's fur.